# Sidemenu and tab issue in iOS - cn1

Tags: codenameone

I have 4 tab in a tabs component and a side menu. If I scroll horizontal the 1st tab from the left side, the side menu tends to appear but it doesn't. However the 1st tab moves horizontally from left to right and white blank screen is seen.

Have a look at the video [here.](https://youtu.be/UJ1n_2aKFp0)

Comment: I'm not sure why that would happen but as I mentioned in the previous question tab swiping and side menu don't mix well.

Answer (score 0):

Using tabs with a side menu is not a good idea. You could try adding a fifth tab and placing commands there instead of a side menu.
It will look the same and it should work better than a side menu.

hope this helps and good luck with your development :)